# Preloading image for all images

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, preloader

I try to add a preloading image for all images with the jQuery `load()` method.
In my php-document I read the image-folder and create an `img-tag` foreach element.

Something like this:

```
$myimages = opendir("img/");
$gallery = array();
while($myimage = readdir($myimages))
{
 if($myimage != '.' AND $myimage != '..')
 {
  $gallery[] = $image;
 }
} 

sort($gallery);

foreach ($gallery as $image) { 
    echo '<div><img src="img/'.$image.'" id="preload"/></div>';
}

closedir($myimages);
```

Now I want to display a "spinner-image" til the images are loaded.
Every try with the `window.load` or `jQuery load` doesn't work for me.

Can anyone explain me what I have to do?

Thanks for your help!

**// edit //**

If I use an extra `div` in `html` it works fine.

Comment: `img{ background-image: url(css/img/spinner.gif) 50% no-repeat; }`

Comment: Hi Roko `img{background: url(css/img/spinner.gif) 50% no-repeat;}` does not wait till the image is fully loaded?

Comment: Have you tried? It's a dummy background placeholder set as image background.

Comment: I tried. The image loads across the spinner.

Comment: You will have duplicate `id`s here which is not allowed..

Comment: Hi putvande - Thank you I havent see that and will try it again probably by class.

Answer (score 0):

you could preloadImages with javascript

```
function preloadImages(array) {
if (!preloadImages.list) {
    preloadImages.list = [];
}
var list = preloadImages.list;
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        var index = list.indexOf(this);
        if (index !== -1) {
            // remove image from the array once it's loaded
            // for memory consumption reasons
            list.splice(index, 1);
        }
    };
    list.push(img);
    img.src = array[i];
}

}
```